# Query for finding the distance between geometries from consecutive rows in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Using ST_Distance would require two geometrical points , wherein i have a single 'geom' column with 50 geometrical records, for which i need to find the distance between the consecutive rows.

Say i need to find the distance between the first and second row, and then the second and third row and so on.

CREATE TABLE "gdata"
(
  device_ID text, data_ID bigserial NOT NULL, geom geometry
)

[Created table]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi9a3.png ]

I have used the following query to order.

select  device_ID, geom from "gdata" ORDER BY device_ID

Therefore i obtain,

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RWig.png]

The expected output is a separate column named "distance" wherein, i calculate the distance between the first geometrical point and the second, then the second geometrical value and the third, and so on, for the succesive number of points in "geom".

Thanks in advance :) !

Comment: Rows in a relational database are not sorted. So there is no such thing as the "first" or "second" row unless you specify an `order by` - which requires some column that defines the sort order. Please **edit** your question and add the complete table definition (as `create table`) some sample data (as _formatted_ text) and the expected output based on that sample data. Ideally create an example at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Hope I've made myself clear :)

Comment: I have no experience with postgis but when you need a value from a preceding row you can use the window function `lag` as in `lag(geom, 1) over (order by device_ID)`.

Comment: Thank you :) I tried that out, but dint know how to integrate with the postGIS function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `lag` function with 1 as offset:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT (lag(data_ID,1) OVER (order by data_ID)) AS from_id,     
         data_ID as to_id,         
         ST_Distance(geom, lag(geom,1) OVER (order by data_ID )) AS distance 
  FROM gdata 
) AS foo WHERE distance IS NOT NULL;
```

Not sure if data_ID is the correct field for the order by. Maybe is device_ID?

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly fine, except for which i had two id columns (from_id, to _id), but that's not a big deal. And the right field for order by is the device_ID :)!